# CSS fixed nav with jquery

Tags: css, nav

I've this CSS, which is the cause of following problem; the nav wont stay fixed. Please help

The problem (since I deleted this, it worked)

```
[canvas] {
    z-index: 1;
}

[canvas=container] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white; /* Basic background color, overwrite this in your own css. */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Enables momentum scrolling on iOS devices, may be removed by setting to 'auto' in your own CSS. */
}

[canvas=container]:before, [canvas=container]:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

/**
 * Off-Canavs
 */

[off-canvas] {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white; /* Basic colors, overwrite this in your own css. */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Enables momentum scrolling on iOS devices, may be removed by setting to 'auto' in your own CSS. */
}

[off-canvas*=top] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    top: 0;
}

[off-canvas*=right] {
    width: 255px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

[off-canvas*=bottom] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 255px;
    bottom: 0;
}

[off-canvas*=left] {
    width: 255px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

[off-canvas*=reveal] {
    z-index: 0;
}

[off-canvas*=push] {
    z-index: 1;
}

[off-canvas*=overlay] {
    z-index: 9999;
}

/**
 * Animation
 */

[canvas], [off-canvas] {
    -webkit-transform: translate( 0px, 0px );
        -ms-transform: translate( 0px, 0px );
            transform: translate( 0px, 0px );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
            transition:         transform 300ms ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Prevents flickering but may be removed if your having problems with fixed background images in Chrome. */
}

/**
 * Print
 */

@media print {
    [canvas] {
        -webkit-transform: translate( 0px, 0px ) !important;
            -ms-transform: translate( 0px, 0px ) !important;
                transform: translate( 0px, 0px ) !important;
    }

    [off-canvas] {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

I've my website within a div called 
And the nav looks like this;

```
nav{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(10,21,31, 0.8), rgba(12,53,72, 0.8), rgba(38,74,81, 0.8));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(10,21,31, 0.8), rgba(12,53,72, 0.8), rgba(38,74,81, 0.8));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(10,21,31, 0.8), rgba(12,53,72, 0.8), rgba(38,74,81, 0.8));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(10,21,31, 0.8), rgba(12,53,72, 0.8), rgba(38,74,81, 0.8));
    color: #fff
}
```

The HTML for the menu (coming from left, not the nav) looks like;

```
<div off-canvas="sb-1 left reveal" id="menu">
    <div class="icono-cross close-any"></div>
</div>
```

And for the nav;

```
<nav></nav>
```

Comment: I added the html for the nav and menu